# WPF - RectangleGeometry animation in C# using a Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, wpf-animation

I need to animate a RectangleGeometry in C#, but I don't know what is the path to use for the ProperyPath.

```
rectAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("What-is-the-path?"));
```

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="Item" Source="{StaticResource ItemDragComplete00bw}" Stretch="None">
   <Image.Clip>
      <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 684, 250" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10">
         <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
            <TransformGroup>
               <ScaleTransform CenterX="342" CenterY="0" ScaleX="0.366" ScaleY="1.0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
         </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
      </RectangleGeometry>
   </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

C#

```
RectAnimation rectAnimation = new RectAnimation();
rectAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(toMills - fromMills);
rectAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
rectAnimation.From = new Rect(xFrom, yFrom, wFrom, hFrom);
rectAnimation.To = new Rect(xTo, yTo, wTo, hTo);

rectAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, target);
rectAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("What-is-the-path?"));

storyboard.Children.Add(rectAnimation);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a Storyboard. Just call

```
var geometry = (RectangleGeometry)Item.Clip;
geometry.BeginAnimation(RectangleGeometry.RectProperty, rectAnimation);
```

Also note that it is usually not necessary to set the animation's `From` property when you simply want to animate from the current value to a new value. The default value of the `FillBehavior` property is also already `HoldEnd`.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to put the RectAnimation inside a Storyboard, so I need the property path string.

Comment: You can run multiple animations parallel, so there is hardly any need for a Storyboard. Besides that, your question can not be answered from the code you are showing. It is unclear what `target` is and the PropertyPath is of course relative to that element.

Comment: The target is the "Item" variable (the Image user control with the .Clip property).

Comment: Then the Path should simply be `"Clip.Rect"`.

Comment: It is also unclear why you do not use the `Storyboard.SetTarget` and  `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty` methods.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work:                                                                  
Storyboard.SetTarget(rectAnimation, rectangleGeometry); Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rectAnimation, new PropertyPath(RectangleGeometry.RectProperty));